# quad.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'

Tags: calculator, quadratic

When trying to write a code for a quadratic equation to figure out the x's, I get an error saying there is a problem with the parenthesis
Here's the code i have entered for this calculator

```
puts "A"
a = gets.to_f
puts "B"
b = gets.to_f
puts "C"
c = gets.to_f

d = (-b+ ((b**2 - 4ac)**1/2))/2a
f = (-b- ((b**2 - 4ac)**1/2))/2a
puts d
puts f
```

and i come out with this error when trying to run it

```
quad.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
d = (-b+ ((b**2 - 4ac)**1/2))/2a
                     ^
quad.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
```

Any help? Thank you very much

Comment: Add four spaces in front of code lines to make them format properly

Comment: Which calculator are you using? TI-Basic differs considerably from Casio's and HP's, for example. Some modern calculators (like the TI nspire) let you omit multiplication operators between symbols, but others require it, so we need more info.

Comment: Please update the formattings of your question now that you on several occasions have been asked to do so and have been told how.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing * in lots of places. E.g. 4 * a * c instead of 4ac

Comment: Thank you Tony for the response, I changed those mistakes and then I'm left with this error

quad.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end

Comment: You need to fix the formatting on your code in your question...very difficult to read

Comment: I'm very new to this, would you know how I would need to format?

Comment: 4 spaces in front of each line

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "I will solve a quadratic equation"
print "What is the value of a in ax^2+bx+c=0?"
a = gets.to_f;
print "What is the value of b in ax^2+bx+c=0?"
b = gets.to_f;
print "What is the value of c in ax^2+bx+c=0?"
c = gets.to_f;

d = b*b - 4*a*c
d = Math.sqrt(d)

e= -b/(2*a)

f= d/(2*a)

puts "The value of first root (x1) is #{e+f}"
puts "The value of second root (xe) is #{e-f}"
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explain how you fixed the code, and why.  Also, note that this question is more than a year old.